# MySQL - Reserving a range of IDs for child objects for each parent object

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Companies and each Company has multiple Products. Models have following relation-

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

I want to reserve 1000 product IDs for each Company.

So

- Company1 can have product IDs from 1-1000
- Company2 can have product IDs from 1001-2000

I want to reserve the PRIMARY keys of Products table for each Company rather than having scoped primary key and duplicate IDs (because a consumer/company can remember product ID and access it using url '.../product/1000').

Solution I have in mind-
Should I create multiple sequences (one for each company as and when company gets created). With default value as (Company.ID -1) * 1000 + 1.
And use nextval for this sequence when product is created for a company 1. I am sure that a company will not have 1000 products in the system (improbable).

Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Just do a normal has_many <-> belongs to association

Comment: There is already a has_many and belongs to association. It will be easy for a company to access the products. We show the product ID everywhere in application (it does not have a name).

Answer (score 1):

Your plan isn't great. If you have 50 companies with 5 products each, now you have 50,000 lines in your database. Databases handle this type of problem all the time. Don't count on your customers remembering database ids. Make it easy for them to find the ids.

You should organize your model in rails like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
class Products < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Try and picture how your changes from the norm create new issues and whether you get a significant boost for your day thinking about deviating from the norm. In your case if a company has 1001 products you just created a lot more work for yourself.

Comment: Association is there. Products do not have names and are identified by IDs and we show the ID on UI throughout the system. Product is identified by too many parameters and I cannot make a name from it (users are already well versed with identifying products from IDs)...

Comment: How do you address a company with 1001 products?

Comment: I probably need to assign the next available block of IDs to it... I do not have a perfect solution so looking for the pointers. This is a requirement from business. :(